# How can I trim a widget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I need to trim a `QWidget`. I need it to be sliced as if a mask were applied and part of it be invisible.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [`QWidget::setMask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setMask)?

Comment: Thanks, it seems https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setMask-1 an overload using `QRegion` may be what I need